# python serial data read code with carriage return \r

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

This is my working code to read the data from the Artix-7 serial port. But it comes form the carriage return. Like;

```
'FFFDB03\r'
'FFFFB606'
'\r00006C0'
'D\rFFFFD8'
'1B\rFFFFB'
'037\r0000'
'606F\rFFF'
'FC0DF\rFF'
'FF81BE\r0'
'000037D\r'
```

how to solve this, can I set the CR and LF in the serial.Serial() settings. If anyone knows please reply

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS 
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE 
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE              
ser.xonxoff = False    
ser.rtscts = False    
ser.dsrdtr = False  

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():
    try:
        ser.flushInput()
        ser.flushOutput()

        while True:
            print repr(ser.read(8))
    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)
else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the synchronization problem is to read until the `\r`.  That can be done by replacing your inner loop with:

```
max_packet = 8
while True:
    data = ser.read_until(terminator='\r', size=max_packet*2)
    print repr(data[:-1])
```

Comment: I tried your solution but first it says read_until - there is no until with read, second if I wrote like ser.read (max_packet*2,'\r') it says three arguments given two required. Any solution

Comment: Which version of pyserial are you using? https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/pyserial-3.2.1/autoapi/serialutil/index.html#serialutil.SerialBase.read_until

Comment: I have one version older let me update and see the result

Comment: Now its working; the only thing is left after each 8 byte it display the '\r' is there any way not to display the \r

Comment: Thanks it works I replace repr with str  it works that way too

Comment: Hi, I got one small problem can you give me a feedback, how to send keystroke to the port; to start receiving the data again